# Invalid JSON primitive: . when deserializing

Tags: json, rest, powershell

I am getting an exception when running my script on Powershell v5:

Exception calling "DeserializeObject" with "1" argument(s): "Invalid JSON primitive: ."
At :264 char:1
+ $Obj = $jsonserial.DeserializeObject($Devices)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArgumentException

A bit of the script below... what am i missing?

```
$useJSON = "application/json"
$headers = Build-Headers $restUserName $tenantAPIKey $useJSON $useJSON

$DeleteTime = (Get-Date).AddDays(-35)

$Devices = Invoke-RestMethod -Method GET -Uri $endpointURL -Headers $headers -TimeoutSec 30

[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Web.Extensions")        
$jsonserial= New-Object -TypeName System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer 
$jsonserial.MaxJsonLength  = [Int32]::MaxValue
$Obj = $jsonserial.DeserializeObject($Devices)

$Devices = $Obj.Devices
```

I would like to add that I don't have this problem when running the script on powershell v4 only on v5...

Comment: Does the `$Devices` variable contain valid json?  Use `Write-Host` or `Write-Verbose` to dump the contents of the variable.

Answer (score 0):

Invoke-RestMethod already converts your server response from JSON. If you want to do it yourself, try Invoke-WebRequest.